# Split raster into smaller tiles of certain size with R

Tags: raster, r, tiles

I have a list of about 100 raster stacks with different location and sizes. To feed them into a neural network I need them to be the size of 256x256 pixels. I've tried splitting them using the tile_geoprocessor function just to realize it does not work with raster stacks but only single bands. The splitRaster function does also not work, since it requires the number of tiles along the x- and x-axis, which is different for every raster.

Is there a way to iterate through my 100 raster stacks splitting them up into 256x256 pixel tiles?

Comment: Are you trying to split the individual raster stack files into 256x256 tiles or are you trying to split the composite mosaic of all 100 files into 256x256 tiles? What's the resolution of each file? Is it a multiple of 256 on each side, or what do you want done with the leftovers?

Comment: I am trying to split each individual raster stack file. The resolution is 10 meters. Some raster files are larger than 256x256 pixels, some are smaller and I'd like to get NA values for the part of the tiles that are not fully filled by the raster stacks. Pretty much I want exactly what the tile_geoprocessor function is doing, but only for raster stacks instead of single band files.

Comment: Where's the `tile_geoprocessor` function coming from? If that works for single bands, then one approach might be to split your stacks into bands, work on the bands, then recombine into stacks.

Comment: I ended up switching over to Python and used gdal_translate and that has worked fine for me.